# Q: (ssg-wsg) Keep getting errors with CorpPass

Tags: authentication

I tried to create an account with SSG-WSG Developer Portal as a Corporate User.  We have a CorpPass that is actively used in multiple sites already, but when we try to sign in to SSG-WSG Developer Portal, we were able to proceed through authentication, but as soon as it tried to re-direct back to SSG-WSG, the SSG-WSG Login dialog box returned "A system error has occured. Please try again."

Comment: Are you able to give us any more information regarding the error? Was there any error code, or is there a possibility to enable logging, as the error that you mentioned is a very general error message.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. No further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a need to assign your Corppass account with "API Developer" role before you can sign in to SSG-WSG Developer Portal.
(Refer to https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/13EgI9eYfms1W7Ls4X1hdI)